# What is causing my gas water heater to make a high pitched noise?

Tags: water-heater, gas, noise

I woke up two mornings ago to water that was colder than usual, so.. I naturally went to check the water heater and the pilot was out, the pilot light has never went out in the 4 years- almost 5 I've owned it. I turned it back on and all was fine until that night, I noticed a high pitched squealing noise like pressure escaping a tiny hole.. I was pretty tired so I waited until the next morning to check it out. When I went back to finally find the source of the noise the next morning, I noticed it was louder than it was that night. I turned the pilot light off first thing, and the noise immediately stopped. As soon as I press the ignition to turn it back on the noise starts again and doesn't stop until the pilot is off.

I have no idea what could be causing it, is it normal ageing or is there a cause for concern? I've pretty much left it like that the past few days and the intensity of the sound hasn't changed but it's becoming annoying real fast.

Comment: Manufacturer and model?

Comment: Gas lines are usually less than 2 PSI, I would think something in the valve itself could be causing the noise. If you have a drip leg prior to the valve you may try turning off the gas supply and opening the drip leg and see if it has filled up with water. I have had water in both a furnace valve and a on-demand water heater valve cause them to go out and made some noise that my wife could hear but I could not.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like either a dirty pilot light or your the flame may be getting into your air venturi. I would have the burner pulled and clean both the pilot burner and main burner including venturi tube.